# bottle web server: how to route to text file

Tags: javascript, python, dynamic, web, bottle

I am writing a web app using bottle. I need to pass certain text files to a javascript function which process the file and displays an image on the web.

I would like to be able to make a route with a variable directory ie

./database/*/CONTCAR.xyz

so that i can call a url of the form ./database/6Ni@32Ag_npo/CONTCAR.xyz and get that CONTCAR.xyz returned, where "6Ni@32Ag_npo" will be different for each URL.

Here is what I have in my server

```
import bottle as b
@b.route('/database/<folder>/CONTCAR.xyz')
  def server_static(filename):
     return b.static_file( "CONTCAR.xyz" , root='./database/<folder>')
```

In my javascript I try to to call the url as follows:

```
<canvas class='xyz' url='/database/6Ni@32Ag_npo/CONTCAR.xyz' filetype='xyz'></canvas>
```

the xyz class is a class that allows me to process this CONTCAR file.

I get the following error:

TypeError: server_static() got an unexpected keyword argument 'folder'
localhost - - [19/Jan/2014 13:10:46] "GET /database/6Ni@32Ag_npo/CONTCAR.xyz?uid=1390158646852 HTTP/1.1" 500 794

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the name `folder` in the route's path, but `filename` as the sole parameter name.  Luckily, the fix is easy: just use the same name in both places.  (And also correct your use of `folder` in `static_file`'s `root` param:

```
@b.route('/database/<folder>/CONTCAR.xyz')
  def server_static(folder):
     return b.static_file('CONTCAR.xyz', root='./database/{}'.format(folder))
```

---

For two levels of folders, you'd do something like this:

```
@b.route('/database/<folder1>/<folder2>/CONTCAR.xyz')
  def server_static(folder1, folder2):
     return b.static_file('CONTCAR.xyz', root='./database/{}/{}'.format(folder1, folder2))
```

Comment: Excellent!  Thank you very much.  This fixed the problem.  One more quick question.  what would the syntax be for `b.route(/database/<folder1>/<folder2>/CONTCAR.xyz`) ?